# Eclipse: Save as .apk in My Computer?

Tags: eclipse, android, export

I have just started learning Android App Development using Eclipse.

I have made a small application.

Anyhow, I am not able to find any option to save my work as a .apk file in any folder of my choice in my Computer.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .apk of your application is a result of your java project, you can't save as .apk  but you can easily export your application as .apk (File -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application), here you can transform your work as a .apk and save this file in the folder you want. [A tutorial (in french but with many images) is available here.](http://harisseldon.blogspot.fr/2011/08/creer-un-ficher-apk-sous-eclipse.html)

Comment: What is the difference between saving and export?

Comment: Saving : You save your java project. Export : You save your java project and you export the content in a .apk, the file format used to distribute and install an Android application. You haven't to export your java project every time you want to launch it, the virtual devices in the SDK are here to win time.